# Tomar valor de manera dinamica

Tags: php, html, jquery

estoy tratando de mandar dos parámetros que necesito a un script de sql, para que me haga una modificación en la base de datos.
Lo que tengo es los siguiente:

```js
$(function() {
    $('.tabla :input').on('change', function(){
       var $input = $(this);
       if($input.val() === 'F'){
           $input.removeClass('verde');
          $input.addClass("rojo"); 
          /*$input.classList.remove('verde');*/
          /* $input.style['background'] = 'red';*/
       } else {
           $input.removeClass('rojo');
           $input.addClass("verde");
           /*$input.classList.remove('rojo');*/
           /*$input.style['background'] = 'green';*/
       }
    });
    $("#ejecutar").click(function(){
        var ano = new Date();
        console.log(ano.getFullYear());
        console.log((ano.getMonth()+1));
        $("input[name='dia[]']").each(function(indice, elemento) {
            console.log('El elemento con el índice '+indice+' contiene '+$(elemento).val());
        });
    });
    $("input").on('change', function(){
        var fecha = $("input").attr("name");
        var placa = $("td").attr("name");
        console.log(placa);
        $.post("modificar.php",{centro: $("#input").attr("name")});
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Serif, Arial, Helvetica, "sans-serif";
  background-color: #31aee7;
  color: white;
}
.placa, .dia{
    font-size: 1.2em;
    background-color:#085584ff;
    width: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
input{
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 0;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1em;
}
/*input[value="1"]{
    background: green;
}
input[value="F"]{
    background: red;
}*/
.rojo {
    background: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.verde {
    background: green;
    font-weight: bold;
}
table, th,td{
  border: 2px solid;
  border-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
   </head>
  <body>
   <table class="tabla">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th width="100" class="placa">Placa</th>
        <th width="100" class="dia">1</th>
        <th width="100" class="dia">2</th>           
        <th width="100" class="dia">3</th>
        <th width="100" class="dia">4</th>
        <th width="100" class="dia">5</th>
        <th width="100" class="dia">6</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" name="abc123">abc123</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="rojo" value="F"                   name="12/1/2019"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="rojo" value="F"                    name="12/2/2019"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="rojo" value="F"                   name="12/3/2019"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="rojo" value="F"                    name="12/4/2019"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="rojo" value="F"                    name="12/5/2019"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="rojo" value="F"                    name="12/6/2019"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
       <tr>
        <td align="center" name="def123">def123</td>               <td><input type="text" class="rojo" value="F"                    name="12/1/2019"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="rojo" value="F"                    name="12/2/2019"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="rojo" value="F"                    name="12/3/2019"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="rojo" value="F"                    name="12/4/2019"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="rojo" value="F"                    name="12/5/2019"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="rojo" value="F"                    name="12/6/2019"></td>
       </tr>
```

Al dar click en algún input si me trae el name del td pero el problema es que siempre me toma el mismo y no se como hacer para que cambie por que la idea es que me traiga cada placa dependiendo donde cambie el input.

Trate por medio de PHP concatenar la placa y la fecha en cada input pero no me los une, la verdad ya no se que mas hacer para darle solución a esto, ya que necesito tanto la fecha como la placa para validar que modifique lo que le pido.

Agradezco mucho la ayuda que me puedan dar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De la forma que lo tienes siempre te va a traer la misma fecha y name.  Necesitas usar el contexto `this` asi:

```js
$(function() {
    $('.tabla :input').on('change', function(){
       var $input = $(this);
       if($input.val() === 'F'){
           $input.removeClass('verde');
          $input.addClass("rojo"); 
          /*$input.classList.remove('verde');*/
          /* $input.style['background'] = 'red';*/
       } else {
           $input.removeClass('rojo');
           $input.addClass("verde");
           /*$input.classList.remove('rojo');*/
           /*$input.style['background'] = 'green';*/
       }
    });
    $("#ejecutar").click(function(){
        var ano = new Date();
        console.log(ano.getFullYear());
        console.log((ano.getMonth()+1));
        $("input[name='dia[]']").each(function(indice, elemento) {
            console.log('El elemento con el índice '+indice+' contiene '+$(elemento).val());
        });
    });
    $("input").on('change', function(){
        var fecha = $(this).attr("name");
        var placa = $(this).parents('tr').find('td:first').attr("name");
        console.log(fecha);
        console.log(placa);
        $.post("modificar.php",{centro: $("#input").attr("name")});
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Serif, Arial, Helvetica, "sans-serif";
  background-color: #31aee7;
  color: white;
}
.placa, .dia{
    font-size: 1.2em;
    background-color:#085584ff;
    width: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
input{
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 0;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1em;
}
/*input[value="1"]{
    background: green;
}
input[value="F"]{
    background: red;
}*/
.rojo {
    background: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.verde {
    background: green;
    font-weight: bold;
}
table, th,td{
  border: 2px solid;
  border-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
   </head>
  <body>
   <table class="tabla">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th width="100" class="placa">Placa</th>
        <th width="100" class="dia">1</th>
        <th width="100" class="dia">2</th>           
        <th width="100" class="dia">3</th>
        <th width="100" class="dia">4</th>
        <th width="100" class="dia">5</th>
        <th width="100" class="dia">6</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" name="abc123">abc123</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="rojo" value="F"                   name="12/1/2019"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="rojo" value="F"                    name="12/2/2019"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="rojo" value="F"                   name="12/3/2019"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="rojo" value="F"                    name="12/4/2019"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="rojo" value="F"                    name="12/5/2019"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="rojo" value="F"                    name="12/6/2019"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
       <tr>
        <td align="center" name="def123">def123</td>               <td><input type="text" class="rojo" value="F"                    name="12/1/2019"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="rojo" value="F"                    name="12/2/2019"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="rojo" value="F"                    name="12/3/2019"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="rojo" value="F"                    name="12/4/2019"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="rojo" value="F"                    name="12/5/2019"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="rojo" value="F"                    name="12/6/2019"></td>
       </tr>
```

Comment: Gracias @alanfcm por tu pronta respuesta, la verdad aun estoy aprendiendo, me sirvio de maravilla.

Answer (score 1):

No te entiendo muy bien lo que necesitas hacer, sin embargo puedo ver que tienes un gran problema al recuperar los atributos nombre en esta sección:

```
var fecha = $("input").attr("name");
var placa = $("td").attr("name");
```

lo que haces con:

```
$("input")
```

es buscar el elemento de tipo input y siempre recuperara el primero que encuentre, lo mismo sucede con :

```
$("td")
```

Solo busca el primer td.

Comentarte que no estas haciendo las cosas para nada bien, los id y name se utilizan para identificar a los elementos no para guardar los valores que queremos recuperar de ellos, para no botar todo lo que hiciste, Intercambia:

```
var fecha = $("input").attr("name");
var placa = $("td").attr("name");
```

por:

```
var fecha = $(this).attr("name");
var placa = $('td:first', $(this).parent().parent()).attr("name");
```

Con eso recuperas tanto el nombre del primer td de la fila y el nombre del input que modificaste.